# wmic result to named text file

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, batch-file

I am writing a batch script to install software that is 32 or 64 bit dependent. I am using "wmic os get osarchitecture" to determine the architecture of the Windows OS.

What I am looking to do is have the WMIC output to a named text file that is based on the output. for example if the result is a 32bit OS then it would create a text file called 32bit.txt or if it is a 64bit OS it would create a text file called 64bit.txt.

That way I can have my batch script run the 32bit installer if 32bit.txt exists or run the 64bit installer if 64bit.txt exists.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why have two different filenames?  Wouldn’t it be simpler to set a variable to either ``32bit`` or ``64bit``?

Comment: The software I am trying to install is the apple mobile device support and application support. they have separate installers based on the architecture, not just a switch. And what you are suggesting may still be possible but as this is new to me I don't know enough about it to do that? :)

Comment: [Worthwelle’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1364917/150988#1364924) demonstrates exactly (more or less) what I’m talking about. You might need to do something like ```IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (apple32) else (apple64)```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable can get you something similar to what you want. It will contain [`x86`, `AMD64`, `ARM64` or `IA64`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details), which you can append to your filename.

For example:

```
wmic os get osarchitecture >%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%.txt
```

You could also use this directly in your batch script to call the installers. For example, I generally have the following file structure for batch installations:

```
root
    x64
        installer.exe
    x86
        installer.exe
```

The batch file will then contain something like:

```
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (set bit=x86) else (set bit=x64)
"%bit%\installer.exe"
```

If you prefer using WMIC, you can accomplish that without using a file:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture ^| find "bit"') do set bit=%%a%%b
```

`bit` would then contain `32bit` or `64bit`.

Comment: Are you sure that `x64` is a valid / expected value for ``%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%``? On my Intel i5-based Dell Inspiron (running 64-bit Windows 7), it is `AMD64`

Comment: @Scott The values are `x86`, `AMD64`, `ARM64` or `IA64`. The batch code sets its own variable with `x64` to reduce the number of values.